# sql query return result based on primary key?

Tags: c#, sql

So i have 2 tables, Tenants & Owners. Owners table has a primary key id, and the tenants table has a owner_id in it to associate which owner owns which apartment.

When performing a search, what kind of query would be needed to get information from both tenant and owner table and return the results back to multiple text boxes?

Comment: what value do you want for your checkboxes?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for SQL Joins.  Joins are used to combine rows from two or more tables based on a common field between them (owner_id).

Answer (score 0):

Write two queries, return two result sets, and parse accordingly.

```
 declare @ownerid int

 select firstname, lastname, address, etc, @ownerid = ownerid from Tenants where firstname = 'Joe' and lastname = 'Blow'

 select firstname, lastname, address, etc from Owners where ownerid = @ownerid
```

Of course use your field names.

Comment: Why do you recommend two queries?

Comment: So you have two sets of data to work with - which is what you need.  An owner and a tenant are two different types of data.  An owner may have many tenants, but that is the only thing they share in common.  My sample is just a sample.  What if you were going the other way and choosing an owner, then listing his tenants?  If you had one query, and did a select * joining both tables, for example, the owner data would repeat in each returned record set with the tenant information.  That is not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're using exactly, but if you were using Telerik, here is some C# code that would do a join and should retrieve a data type with what you need in it.

```
CustomDataType cType = from t in context.orm.Tenants
                        join o in context.orm.Owners on t.owner_id equals o.ID
                        select new CustomDataType
                        {
                          .......
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tenants t
join owner o on o.ownerId = t.ownerId
where t.name = 'name'
```

From there select whatever columns you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Tenants 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Owners ON dbo.tbl_tenants.ownerId  
WHERE ownerName = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

But would need to know more about what information you want to get to provide more help.

If you just want all the information form both tables then @TheGeekYouNeed has provided the solution